# In WebStorm, how do I exclude js files generated from ts/tsx?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

When I use `Enable Typescript Compiler`, the TypeScript compiler generates a `.js` file for every `.ts` and `.tsx` file.

[image: Enable Typescript Compiler]

When doing code completion, WebStorm does not know that the files were generated and therefore it suggests completion from the generated files as well as from the TypeScript files. To prevent this, I have to go to every generated `.js` file and right click and `Mark as Plain Text`:

[image: Mark as Plain Text]

However, when I do a text search, I still get the hits from the generated JavaScript files:

[image]

Is there a simple way to exclude the generated files the way it is possible to exclude directories (except for creating a scope that excludes all the generated files)?

Answer (score 3):

Text search supports scopes. I'd suggest adding a custom scope in `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes` with your generated files excluded and using this scope in the `Find in Path` dialog as the custom scope.

Comment: you have already rejected 2 solutions. Sorry, but there is nothing more I can suggest

Comment: It is a bit annoying to add a few hundred files by hand to the scope. I would have hoped that the IDE itself can recognize generated files. What I do is to generate the scope string is this: `find . -not -path './node_modules/*' -not -path './typings/*' \( -name '*.ts' -o -name '*.tsx' \) |sed 's/^\.\/\(.*\)\.tsx\{0,1\}$/\&\&!file:\1.js/g'|tr -d '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open WebStorm Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) and then select the **TypeScript** options.
2. Check the box for **Use output path**, and enter a directory name (relative to project directory). For example, `build/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$` -- the variable is important to avoid potential naming conflicts. It's best to use a build output directory that is excluded by `.gitignore` (assuming Git repo).

[image]

3. Exclude the directory from indexing by right-clicking it from the Project pane, and choosing **Mark Directory As > Excluded**.

(Tested with WebStorm 2016.1.1 on OS X El Capitan)

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not work in my setup, because there is a build process (which I cannot influence) that requires the generated files to be next to the source files (else the imports do not work).